# Hooking keyboard events in .NET MAUI (specifically Android)

Tags: android, .net, maui

I'm porting an Android app that I prototyped in Xamarin Forms. The device that I'm targeting has hardware buttons that must trigger actions in the application. In Xamarin I was able to override `ICallback.OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode,KeyEvent e)` in an `Activity`. I haven't been able to find any equivalent in MAUI. I was expecting `<InputBinding/>` like WPF or maybe an event or override on an `Element`. Is there any way I can achieve this? Maybe even with Android-specific code?

Comment: I have the same issue porting one of my NuGets - https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Xamarin.Forms.StateButton/blob/e56a3c037ed8dbd7e5235a0987df200aea13810c/Scr/StateButton.Android/StateButtonRenderer.cs#L95

Have raised an issue here for it - https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/275#discussioncomment-3351185

Comment: Are you using a Zebra Scan Gun?  If so you might want to look into StageNow capabilities.  You can remap keys like P1 to some printable character like '+'.  This is problematic as you now have to add extra code to strip these characters out and perform processing on them.  StageNow also has capabilities to send Intents but as of yet I have not been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I have found - for Android only - is this (copy from my answer to another question: [MAUI How to use KeyEvent.Callback in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192874/maui-how-to-use-keyevent-callback-in-an-android-app/74446479#74446479)):

1. Define an interface to implement in your pages that you want to "react" to physical keyboard keys (optional - it is used to differentiate pages that you want to react to keys from pages that is not necessary to). A sample:

   ```
   #if ANDROID
   using Android.Views;
   #endif

   namespace KeyboardTest
   {
       public interface IOnPageKeyDown
       {
   #if ANDROID
       /// <summary>
       /// Called when a key is pressed.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="keyCode">The code of pressed key.</param>
       /// <param name="e">Description of the key event.</param>
       /// <returns>
       /// Return true to prevent this event from being propagated further, 
       /// or false to indicate that you have not handled this event and it should continue to be propagated.
       /// </returns>
       public bool OnPageKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e);
   #endif
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement this interface to every page you want to react to keys. Sample:

   ```
   #if ANDROID
   using Android.Views;
   #endif

   // Your code here

   namespace KeyboardTest
   {
       public partial class TestPage : ContentPage, IOnPageKeyDown
       {
           #if ANDROID
           public bool OnPageKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
           {
              switch (keyCode)
              {
               case Keycode.DpadUp:
                // Your code here
               return true;

               case Keycode.DpadDown:
                // Your code here
               return true;

               case Keycode.Enter:
                // Your code here
               return true;

               default:
                  return false;
              }
           }
           #endif
       }
   }
   ```
3. Override "OnKeyDown" in Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs. Sample:

   ```
   using Android.App;
   using Android.Content.PM;
   using Android.OS;
   using Android.Runtime;
   using Android.Views;
   using AndroidX.Core.View;

   namespace KeyboardTest;

   // Your code here

   public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
   {
    // Your code here

      public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
      {
         Page p = Shell.Current.CurrentPage;

         if (p is IOnPageKeyDown)
         {
             bool handled = (p as IOnPageKeyDown).OnPageKeyDown(keyCode, e);

             if (handled) return true;
             else return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
         }
         else return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
      }
   }
   ```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Android doesn't do keyboard events from the soft keyboard.  It does commitText calls.  Some frameworks fake keyboard events from it, but they're not accurate.  The onKeyDown in Activity is only applicable to physical keys-  power, volume, etc.  So you can't rely on keyboard events happening at all, and even when they do, you can't trust any data in them other than printable keys.  Timing data, up and downs, and meta keys (shift, ctrl, etc) will be completely wrong.

The Android way to do things is to use a TextWatcher on the text field.  I have no idea how that translates to your framework.

Comment: Let me reiterate that the request is for HARDWARE BUTTONS.  In my case I have a Zebra Scan Gun which has hardware keys for numbers, letters, enter, escape, shift, P1, P2, F1 to F12 keys.  I want to detect when P1, P2, F1, etc is pressed.  These are non-printable characters which will not be detected in a TextWatcher.

Comment: @D.Kermott What are you talking about?  You didn't post this question, and nothing about this is in the question. So I'm not sure where you got this from, but you're seriously confused.

Comment: pfff.  Did you read the request?  "Hardware Buttons"  maybe you missed that or YOU are seriously confused.