# MAUI How to use KeyEvent.Callback in an Android app

Tags: c#, maui

The application is written for the data collection terminal (android). It has a physical keyboard. Can you tell me how to intercept keyboard clicks if there is no text field on the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution that I have found is this:

1. Define an interface to implement in your pages that you want to "react" to physical keyboard keys (optional - it is used to differentiate pages that you want to react to keys from pages that is not necessary to). A sample:

   ```
   #if ANDROID
   using Android.Views;
   #endif

   namespace KeyboardTest
   {
       public interface IOnPageKeyDown
       {
   #if ANDROID
       /// <summary>
       /// Called when a key is pressed.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="keyCode">The code of pressed key.</param>
       /// <param name="e">Description of the key event.</param>
       /// <returns>
       /// Return true to prevent this event from being propagated further, 
       /// or false to indicate that you have not handled this event and it should continue to be propagated.
       /// </returns>
       public bool OnPageKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e);
   #endif
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement this interface to every page you want to react to keys. Sample:

   ```
   #if ANDROID
   using Android.Views;
   #endif

   // Your code here

   namespace KeyboardTest
   {
       public partial class TestPage : ContentPage, IOnPageKeyDown
       {
           #if ANDROID
           public bool OnPageKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
           {
              switch (keyCode)
              {
               case Keycode.DpadUp:
                // Your code here
               return true;

               case Keycode.DpadDown:
                // Your code here
               return true;

               case Keycode.Enter:
                // Your code here
               return true;

               default:
                  return false;
              }
           }
           #endif
       }
   }
   ```
3. Override "OnKeyDown" in Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs. Sample:

   ```
   using Android.App;
   using Android.Content.PM;
   using Android.OS;
   using Android.Runtime;
   using Android.Views;
   using AndroidX.Core.View;

   namespace KeyboardTest;

   // Your code here

   public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
   {
    // Your code here

      public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
      {
         Page p = Shell.Current.CurrentPage;

         if (p is IOnPageKeyDown)
         {
             bool handled = (p as IOnPageKeyDown).OnPageKeyDown(keyCode, e);

             if (handled) return true;
             else return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
         }
         else return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
      }
   }
   ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That is perfect!  The keycodes work perfectly on an android zebra scan-gun.  This is THE best solution.  I'll start directing people to this page.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I've had a couple issues since using this method.  On the scan-gun the trigger and the P2 button on the hardware keyboard both results in a Keycode.ButtonL1.  I ended up not using the P2 button on some screens because of this.

Another issue I'm still trying to track down.  After hitting a key the app hangs before prompting with a Close or Wait message.  In the debugger the OnPageKeyDown event is not firing.

Comment: @D.Kermott: On my Zebra scan-gun (model MC330L) there is not P2 key, so I can not test this. Except that, the sample code I have presented works only if a focused view/control has NOT handled the keypress already (I think that this is the reason the event is not firing - I have not the same problem with debugging). If an Entry (for example) has the focus, you have to install a handler for this Entry, to change the way it handles keypresses. I hope that this helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnKeyListener` Class can be used to deal with the input from the physical keyboard:

```
 public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnKeyListener
{
    public bool OnKey(Android.Views.View v, [GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
         return true;// true will intercept keyboard clicks
    }
}
```

And add the listener to the entry when there is no text field on the form:

```
private void entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Entry entry = (Entry)sender;
#if ANDROID
    (entry.Handler.PlatformView as AppCompatEditText).SetOnKeyListener(new MyListener());
#endif
 }
```

And when the form has text, remove the listener:

```
Entry entry = (Entry)sender;
#if ANDROID
    (entry.Handler.PlatformView as AppCompatEditText).SetOnKeyListener(null);
#endif
```